# VMware player unable to start services

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-workstation

Hi my vmware player is unable to start because of kernel module updater. When I do "install updates" , it just stops services, doing something at background and stops immediately telling that "Unable to start services" . Probably problem stems from vmware network adapter. Here is my environment infos:

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Arch: x64

Kernel: Linux my-pc 4.13.0-26-generic #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 22:00:44 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Soft: Vmware player 12.5.9

Log file:

```
2018-01-14T16:55:06.962+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Log for VMware Workstation pid=13022 version=12.5.9 build=build-7535481 option=Release

2018-01-14T16:55:06.962+04:00| vthread-4| I125: The process is 64-bit.

2018-01-14T16:55:06.962+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8

2018-01-14T16:55:06.962+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Host is Linux 4.13.0-26-generic Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

2018-01-14T16:55:06.962+04:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.

2018-01-14T16:55:06.962+04:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.

2018-01-14T16:55:06.962+04:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.

2018-01-14T16:55:06.962+04:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /root/.vmware/config. Using default values.

2018-01-14T16:55:06.962+04:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Unable to check permissions for preferences file.

2018-01-14T16:55:06.962+04:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.

2018-01-14T16:55:06.962+04:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Failed to load user preferences.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.009+04:00| vthread-4| W115: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-13022.log

2018-01-14T16:55:07.021+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.021+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Created new pathsHash.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.021+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.13.0-26-generic to "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.021+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-26-generic".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.021+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h

2018-01-14T16:55:07.021+04:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.021+04:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check

2018-01-14T16:55:07.028+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-26-generic".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.028+04:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-26-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!

2018-01-14T16:55:07.168+04:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/Module.symvers

2018-01-14T16:55:07.168+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/Module.symvers.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.190+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 22181 symbol versions

2018-01-14T16:55:07.190+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmmon module.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.190+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmnet module.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.190+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmblock module.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.190+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmci module.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.190+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vsock module.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.190+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting vsock to depend on vmci.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.190+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.192+04:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.192+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.193+04:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.194+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmblock".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.195+04:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.195+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmci".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.197+04:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.197+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vsock".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.199+04:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.216+04:00| vthread-4| I125: to be installed: vmnet status: 0

2018-01-14T16:55:07.236+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.236+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.13.0-26-generic to "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.236+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-26-generic".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.236+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h

2018-01-14T16:55:07.236+04:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.236+04:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check

2018-01-14T16:55:07.243+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-26-generic".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.243+04:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-26-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!

2018-01-14T16:55:07.372+04:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/Module.symvers

2018-01-14T16:55:07.372+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/Module.symvers.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.394+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 22181 symbol versions

2018-01-14T16:55:07.394+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Kernel header path retrieved from FileEntry: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include

2018-01-14T16:55:07.396+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Update kernel header path to /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include

2018-01-14T16:55:07.396+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-26-generic".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.396+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h

2018-01-14T16:55:07.396+04:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.396+04:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check

2018-01-14T16:55:07.402+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-26-generic".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.402+04:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-26-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!

2018-01-14T16:55:07.403+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Found compiler at "/usr/bin/gcc"

2018-01-14T16:55:07.406+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Got gcc version "5.4.0".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.406+04:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.406+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Using user supplied compiler "/usr/bin/gcc".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.409+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Got gcc version "5.4.0".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.409+04:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.410+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "4.13.0-26-generic".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.410+04:00| vthread-4| I125: No matching PBM set was found for kernel "4.13.0-26-generic".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.410+04:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.410+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-26-generic".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.410+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h

2018-01-14T16:55:07.410+04:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.410+04:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check

2018-01-14T16:55:07.418+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-26-generic".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.418+04:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-26-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!

2018-01-14T16:55:07.419+04:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.419+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-26-generic".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.419+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h

2018-01-14T16:55:07.419+04:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.419+04:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check

2018-01-14T16:55:07.427+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-26-generic".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.427+04:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-26-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!

2018-01-14T16:55:07.427+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Using temp dir "/tmp".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.429+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.429+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.13.0-26-generic to "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.429+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.13.0-26-generic".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.429+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h

2018-01-14T16:55:07.429+04:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.429+04:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check

2018-01-14T16:55:07.438+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.13.0-26-generic".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.438+04:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.13.0-26-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!

2018-01-14T16:55:07.570+04:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/Module.symvers

2018-01-14T16:55:07.570+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/Module.symvers.

2018-01-14T16:55:07.591+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 22181 symbol versions

2018-01-14T16:55:07.591+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".

2018-01-14T16:55:07.593+04:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.

2018-01-14T16:55:08.491+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".

2018-01-14T16:55:08.491+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".

2018-01-14T16:55:08.499+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.

2018-01-14T16:55:08.499+04:00| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j8 -C /tmp/modconfig-lAVtko/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"

2018-01-14T16:55:10.691+04:00| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```